# Get the field from the nested array

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am getting response from airline `webservice` in this variable `BookingDetailsEmailRS[]` bookingDetailsEmailRS.
I want to get Travelers field in the nested array. 
fill this field in my grid view Travelers Name column.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GatewayBookingClient b = new GatewayBookingClient();

    string emailid = "mshrivastava@fareportal.com";

    string errorCode = string.Empty;
    string errorAtNode = string.Empty;

    SoapAuthentication soap = new SoapAuthentication();
    soap.UserName = "peter@mobissimo.com";
    soap.Password = "mob1ss1mo1947";
    BookingDetailsEmailRS[] bookingDetailsEmailRS = b.GetBookingDetails(soap, emailid, out  errorCode, out  errorAtNode);

    for (int i = 0; i < bookingDetailsEmailRS.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }  
}
```

I successfully fetched value from the array but another problem is that I want to bind each value of  name variable in the "TravellerName" column in the grid. "TravellerName" column created my own in the grid.

```
    string name = bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].Travelers[0].FirstName +  
    bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].Travelers[0].MiddleName +  
    bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].Travelers[0].LastName;
```

Comment: Since you are asking for help with a very specific problem you might want to assist those suppose to help you by displaying the `BookingDetailsEmailES` class. Even better you could rewrite the example in a more generic manner with example classes and a condensed code example.

Comment: yes I agree with you. I want only example of this problem.

Comment: do you wan to have a single column from the service and other from your own and then want to bind the grid?

Comment: show BookingDetailsEmailRS class structure...

Comment: @krshekhar Other column already field by my own but Travelers Name column in grid view was display empty because this field contain inside array for ex. when I debug my application. I got Travelers Name in the bookingDetailsEmailRS[0] variable. I fetch this field from each variable and fill into Travelers Name column.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Linq IEnumerable` to assign those values from `object array` to GridView as follow.....

```
GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS.Select(obj=>obj.Travelers).Select(x=>x.FirstName+x.MiddleName+x.LastName).ToList();
```

if you are getting only one `Travelers` in bookingDetailsEmailRS then you can directly write as follow...

```
GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS.Select(obj=>obj.Travelers[0].FirstName+obj.Travelers[0].MiddleName+obj.Travelers[0].LastName)).ToList();
```

EDIT:-
If you want all the columns along with above concatnated one then try following...

```
GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS.Select(obj=>new {
    Username =obj.Travelers[0].FirstName+obj.Travelers[0].MiddleName+obj.Travelers[0].LastName,
    obj.property1,
    obj.property2
}).TolIst();
```

Comment: ,thanks for your second solution but I want to add this column in existing gridview1. 
GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS.Select(obj=>obj.Travelers[0].FirstName+obj.Travelers[0].MiddleName+obj.Travelers[0].LastName).ToList();            
 GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS;
   GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: I hope, you understand my problem. I want to resultant column in my gridview.

Comment: please see edit...is this what u want to display whole obj in gridview?let me know.

Comment: It's give error property1 and property2 definition not found.

Comment: Property1,property2 are just for your references..don't write it...you mast have written properties in your "bookingDetailsEmailRS" class..these must be the columns which you want to show in gridview

Comment: when I insert columns. It's give error like                 GridView1.DataSource = bookingDetailsEmailRS.Select(obj => new
            {
                Username = obj.Travelers[0].FirstName + obj.Travelers[0].MiddleName + obj.Travelers[0].LastName,
                obj.BookingNumber,
                obj.BookingStatus
            }).TolIst();

Comment: Error :-  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'TolIst' and no extension method 'TolIst' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It is ToList() not TolIst()...my typing mistake...but you shoud be getting this error on compilation...change it to ToList();

Comment: hey Amol..can you tell me the name of this technique. you used here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the code

```
string name = bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].Travelers[0].FirstName + bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].Travelers[0].MiddleName + bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].Travelers[0].LastName;
```

by returning dataset from the service. In this case you want to return dataset instead of list, arrays.

**If you are returning a List you can get the code by**

```
string name = bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].FirstName + bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].MiddleName + bookingDetailsEmailRS[i].LastName;
```

because bookingDetailsEmailRS[] is the List/array of BookingDetailsEmailRS class.

Thank you